# Does the 'init' hook works for all sites in multisite?

Tags: multisite

Im trying to trigger a configuration everytime I create a new subsite on multisite environment, like so:

```
add_action('init', 'mgh_set_events_option', 99); 
function mgh_set_events_option(){
  $mgh_is_set_options = get_option('mgh_is_set_options');
    if(!$mgh_is_set_options){
        print_r('setting options');
        update_option( 'mgh_is_set_options', true );
    }
}
```

The problem is that the 'init' action does not trigger in some sites from our multisite instance. There is any principle of why this happens?

Comment: Is this code in a plugin? Is that plugin active on all sites?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi, not a plugin, only a snippet on functions.php

Comment: I think the problem is less what you're doing, and more _where_ you're doing it

Comment: If it's in a theme's `functions.php`, it'll only run on sites where that theme is active. You can ensure that it's active on *all* your sites by putting that code snippet into a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) that's active on every site (or in a [Must-Use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)).

Comment: @PatJ you should leave that as an answer not a comment, Jacobs answer is also in the right direction

Comment: you can also consider registering the setting `mgh_is_set_options` which allows you to specify a default value. Then no hook would be needed to do this, it would just auto-magically happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is in a theme's `functions.php`, it'll only run on sites where that theme is active. You can ensure that it's active on *all* your sites by putting that code snippet into a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) that's active on every site (ie, Network Activated). Alternately, you can use a [Must-Use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) to ensure that it runs on every site in your Multisite network.

Comment: Thanks! My theme was deactivated, that's why the init wasn't triggering!

Answer (score 2):

The `init` hook will run whenever WordPress is loaded. So if you have a plugin or theme that uses the `init` hook activated on multiple sites it will work on all sites that the plugin or theme is active on.

However, the hook will only run for the site that is loaded. If you load a page on Site A your callback will run and update the option on Site A, but it will not update the option on Site B until a page on Site B is loaded and the hook is run for that site.